# R changing labels in an animated map using ggplotly and geom_sf

Tags: r, r-sf, ggplotly

I want to create an animated map that shows the number of incidents over time in Pittsburgh, PA (by neighborhood). I can create the map, but I can't figure out how to add the name of the Neighborhood in the tooltip. This is my code so far.

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)


#Downloading shapefile
download.file("http://pghgis-pittsburghpa.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/dbd133a206cc4a3aa915cb28baa60fd4_0.zip",
              destfile = "Pittsburgh_Neighborhoods",mode = 'wb')
unzip("Pittsburgh_Neighborhoods", exdir = ".")

Neighborhoods <-  st_read("Neighborhoods_.shp") %>% 
  st_transform(crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")

#Creating fake data
dates <- seq(as.Date('2017-01-01'),as.Date('2019-12-31'),by = "1 month")
count <- sample(1:30,3240,replace=T)
neigh <- Neighborhoods$hood

df <- merge(dates,neigh)
colnames(df) <- c("Month_Yr", "Neighborhood")
df$count <- count
df$Month_Yr <- format(df$Month_Yr, "%Y-%m") ##Changing to charch

#Merging data frame with neighborhoods layers
map_data <- merge(Neighborhoods, df, by.x = "hood", by.y = "Neighborhood")

#######Create plot with text
p_map2 <- ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = Neighborhoods, colour = "#ffffff20", fill = "#2d2d2d60", size = .5) +
  geom_sf(data = map_data, aes(fill = count, frame = Month_Yr,
                               text = paste0(
                                 "Neighborhood: ", hood, "\n",
                                 "Month Year: ", Month_Yr, "\n",
                                 "Number of fake incidents: ", count
                               ))) +

  ggtitle("Fake incidents over time in Pittsburgh") +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "magma",begin = 0.1, direction = -1) +
  theme_void() + 
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank(), axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank())

#animating the map using ggplotly
pg_map2 <- p_map2 %>%
  ggplotly(tooltip = "text") %>% ##adding the text in the tooltip
  style(hoverlabel = list(bgcolor = "white"), hoveron = "fill") %>%
  plotly_build()

#for some weird reason, the map animates the polygons and not the data, correcting that... 
pg_map2$x$frames <- lapply(
  pg_map2$x$frames, function(f) { 
    f$data <- lapply(f$data, function(d) d[!names(d) %in% c("x", "y")])
    f 
  })

#Adding animation bar
pg_map2 %>% 
  animation_button(
    x = 1, xanchor = "right", y = 0, yanchor = "bottom"
  ) %>%
  animation_slider(
    currentvalue = list(prefix = "Month Year ", font = list(color="red"))
  )
```

But when I hover over the map in any neighborhood and click play or drag the slider, all the legend changes. For instance,  this neighborhood should be "Central business district." Is there a way to keep the name of the neighborhood the same and only change the counts and date (if you are hovering a specific area)?

[image: Date 2017_3]

[image: Date 2017_5]

Thanks so much in advance

Comment: I am running your code now. On my side, I see "Central business district" at the same place all the time. I wonder what is causing your situation.

Comment: Why does it run so slowly?

Comment: @jazzurro  thanks for your response. What R version do you have? Simon Woodward, I am not sure, when I run the code sometimes takes too long, sometimes is fast.

Comment: @NataliaP I am using the latest version (3.6.2) on a windows machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using R 3.6.1, plotly 4.9.1 and ggplot '3.2.1'.

My guess is that the `gplotly()` function is not converting the ggplot object to plotly correctly. Maybe there are some issues with sf plots and animations when converting to plotly. If you look in your `pg_map2$x$frames` object, you will see that each frame has a different number of elements in the data field. And I think each element is supposed to be one of the neighborhood polygons. So the number of elements should not change from one frame to the other.

I think this is the reason you are getting that weird behavior in the animation. And probably the same reason the labels are changing.

What I did was work directly in the plotly API. This seems to have solved the problem. I am filtering 5 months of data just to make the rendering lighter (it was taking some time to render the whole dataset).

```
# Merging data frame with neighborhoods layers and adding a column with the tip text
map_data <- merge(Neighborhoods, df, by.x = "hood", by.y = "Neighborhood") %>%
  mutate(text=paste0("Neighborhood: ", hood, "\n","Month Year: ", Month_Yr, "\n","Number of fake incidents: ", count))

map_data %>% filter(Month_Yr %in% c("2017-01", "2017-02", "2017-03", "2017-04", "2017-05")) %>%
  plot_ly(stroke = I("black"), split=~hood, color=~count, text=~text, showlegend = FALSE, hoverinfo = "text", hoveron = "fills", frame=~Month_Yr) %>%
  style(hoverlabel = list(bgcolor = "white")) %>% 
  animation_slider(currentvalue = list(prefix = "Month Year ", font = list(color="red"))) %>%
  layout(title="Fake incidents over time in Pittsburgh")
```

[image]

[image]

Two good tutorials for making maps in R and plotly

https://blog.cpsievert.me/2018/03/30/visualizing-geo-spatial-data-with-sf-and-plotly/

https://plotly-r.com/maps.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much!! I didn't know I could do the map directly using plot_ly, even though I read before the tutorials you recommended. I guess I was focusing only on  geom_sf and skipped the other parts. The only problem using Plotly is that as you mentioned, it does take a lot of time to render the whole dataset; it seems it runs faster using the gplotly() function.